# 12.04 Unity 2D - dragging windows barely works

Tags: unity, vmware, unity-2d, window, snap-windows

I'm currently running 12.04 in VMWare Player on a Windows 7 64bit machine and I'm experiencing a lot of trouble with dragging windows around.

One of my biggest issues is that very often I'll snap a window off from its maximized state, by dragging it down a couple of inches to the middle of the screen. Then the instant I try to drag it again, it will one of three times (very roughly) maximize back up to full size. If this is something like the Home window, it will almost always accidentally lead to having that initial click n drag start dragging a folder on disk to some other folder. I have moved my Dropbox folder gosh knows where several times.

I tried disabling Grid and Snapping Windows in CompizConfig Settings Manager, but that doesn't seem to be making any difference.

In addition to this, I've been having trouble just dragging windows in general. Sometimes the drag will not register at all, and the cursor changes from a hand to a regular pointer right after I click. No idea what's going on.

What do I do? How I disable all these niceties? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! The issue was reproducing in Windows as well. Turns out my main mouse is bouncing, so it will register a double-click once in a while in any OS. Nothing Unity-related.